# MVC - which methods should be in Model class except set/get members?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, controller

**Should** methods that manipulate the *Model* class members be implemented in the *Model* or in the *Controller*? Does it depend on how "heavy" this manipulation is ?

By "manipulation" I mean:

1. get a class member
2. make a long calculation based upon this class member
3. return another value which relates to this class

For example, a `Board class` which hold a cell matrix member. 
Now I want to implement a method which returns all the surrounding cells according to specific cell location.

Is the model or view responsible to for implementing the above ?

If this question belongs to another Stack Exchange QA site I will welcome the recommendation to move my post to that site.

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulation"? Maybe a few examples would help.

Comment: @s.m. I explained in the edit

Comment: There are some interesting threads here on SO about where to put algorithms in a MVC project. [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376459/mvc-design-pattern). Note that it's a slightly subjective topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you call "model" is are actually [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject). The actual model in MVC is just a layer, not concrete thing.

In your particular example, the `Board` should have a method that returns this list. I assume, that you are actually acquiring it because you then need to do further interaction with those cells.

This is where the [services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29) within the model layer comes in to play. If you use them, they are the outer part of model layer and contain the application logic - interaction between different domain objects and the interaction between the persistence (usually either [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) or [units of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)) and domain objects.

> Let's say you are making a game, and you and player performs and AoE attack. Controller takes a hold of service, which is responsible for this functionality and sends a command: *this player aimed AoE in this direction, perform it*.
>
> Service instantiates `Board` and asks for surrounding cells of the target location. Then it performs "damage" on every cell in the collection that it acquired. After the logic is done, it tell the Unit of Work instance to commit all the changes, that happened on the `Board`.

Controller does not care about the details of what service does. And it should not receive any feedback. When execution gets to the view, it request from model layer the latest changes and modifies the UI. As the added benefit - services let you stop the business logic from leaking in the presentation layer (mostly made up from views an controllers).

The domain object should contain only methods, that deal with their state.

Answer (score 17):

Keep your controllers thin, don't let them do much, this aligns with the Single Responsibility Principle in SOLID for Object Oriented Design. If you have fat controllers, they become hard to test and maintain.

As for the models, I used to have dumb models before that did nothing but to map to database tables and that was inspired by most of the sample applications that you see on the web, but now I don't do that.

I (try to) follow the principles from Domain Driven Design, where models (entities in DDD terms) are at the center of the application, they are expected to encapsulate behaviour related to the entity, they are smart models (so yes, the logic related to an object will live with it in that case). DDD is a much bigger topic and it is not related directly to MVC, but the principles behind it helps you better design your applications, there is a lot of materials and sample apps available if you google DDD.

Additionally, Ruby On Rails community - which seems to inspire most of MVC frameworks - also seems to have a hype around having Fat Models and Skinny Controllers.

On top of that, you can add **View Models** to your mix which I find helpful. In this case, you can have a ViewModel to represent a dumb subset of your model(s) just to use for generating the view, it makes your life easier and further separate your Views from your Models so that they don't affect your design decisions unnecessarily.

Answer (score 7):

I think this has little to do with MVC, and a lot more to do with regular software engineering.

I personally wouldn't hesitate to stick trivial calculations in a model, but would be extremely wary of *fat* models.

Now, the fact that MVC stands for Model View Controller doesn't necessarily mean that *everything* should be either a view, a model or a controller. If you feel the need to move responsibilities to a separate class that doesn't really qualify as an M, a V or a C, I don't see why you shouldn't do it.

The way you implement it is up to you. You could either use this separate class as a "top level" (for lack of a better term) object, or make a method of the model delegate to it, so as to hide the fact that you're using it. I would probably go for the latter.

Everything is debatable, though. Everybody and their sister seem to have a different opinion on how to do MVC right.

Me, I just consider it a guideline. Sure, it's a great idea because it leads you to a better separation of concern, but in the end—as it always happens—there's no one-size-fits-all way to apply it, and you should not be overly constrained by it, to the point where everything has to be either a view, a model or a controller.

Answer (score -2):

As per best practice we should use properties for Calculated fields with get access only. example  public double TotalCost {
            get
            {
                return this.Role.Cost * TotalHour;
            }
        }